# How to extract the connection.username and replace in XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have an XML file to edit using PowerShell.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InitFile version="1.0">
    <SecureReadOnlyFields value="true"/>
    <file-browser>
        <allow-upload value="true"/>
        <root url="D:\Temp\"/>
        <folder url="pa_wf"/>
        <folder url="fsa"/>
        <folder url="CG"/>
    </file-browser>
    <HibernateConfigurations>
        <HibernateDefaultSecurityKey value="ATF"/>
        <HibernateConfiguration name="USER_AUT_FRA_WFSE">
            <session-factory>
                <property name="connection.driver_class">xxxxxx</property>
                <property name="connection.url">xxxxx</property>
                <property name="connection.username">USER_AUT</property>
            </session-factory>
```

Code to read the XML file:

```bsh
$inixml = (Get-Content -Path D:\init.xml)
$upinit = $inixml | ConvertTo-Xml
$node = $upinit.SelectNodes("//property")
```

The last line in code is not giving any O/P. Edit the line containing "connection.username" using PowerShell with USER_AUT_PAR instead of USER_AUT.

Comment: why are you using `ConvertTo-XML`? that is for making PS objects into XML, not the other way around. [*grin*]

Comment: that does not seem to be valid XML. are you sure it is all there AND that it is valid?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something like this:
`[xml]$x = get-content 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\Alphabet.xml`'

then each item in the xml file you can access by ...

```
$x.alphabetFile

xmlns                                          xsi                                       schemaLocation                                              trainer            
-----                                          ---                                       --------------                                              -------            
urn:schemas-microsoft-com:tabletpc:alphabet.v1 http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance urn:schemas-microsoft-com:tabletpc:alphabet.v1 Alphabet.xsd {trainer, traine...
```

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

`ConvertTo-Xml` does not do what you apparently think it does. If you take an actual look at the result of your conversion you'll see something like this:

```
PS C:\> $inixml.Save([Console]::Out)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;InitFile version="1.0"&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;SecureReadOnlyFields value="true"/&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;file-browser&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;allow-upload value="true"/&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;root url="D:\Temp\"/&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;folder url="pa_wf"/&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;folder url="fsa"/&gt;&
...
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml?view=powershell-3.0):

> ### Description
>
> The `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet ***creates an XML-based representation of one or more Microsoft .NET Framework objects***. To use this cmdlet, pipe one or more objects to the cmdlet, or use the InputObject parameter to specify the object.

Emphasis mine.

To properly load the XML data use this:

```
$inixml = New-Object Xml
$inixml.Load('D:\init.xml')
```

Then you'll be able to select the `<property>` nodes as you expected:

```
PS C:\> $inixml.SelectNodes('//property')

name                    #text
----                    -----
connection.driver_class xxxxxx
connection.url          xxxxx
connection.username     USER_AUT
```